# DLE. Скрыть статью для определенного пользователя

Tags: php, dle

Авторизованный пользователь нажал на кнопку и статья больше ему не показывалась?

Она просто бы скрывалась для определенного юзера.

Алгоритм:
1. Человек заходит на сайт
2. Авторизовывается
 
3. Видит все новости на сайте
4. Нажимает на кнопку "скрыть" у определенной статьи. Больше статья с данным ID ему не показывается.

!!!Для других пользователей статья видна, пока они также не скроют ее.

Помогите реализовать подобное. Я уверен пару строчек кода нужно там. Не могу сориентироваться.

Comment: Вытащил ID пользователя и остальные данные. Но не могу найти, как именно для него скрыть статью с определенным ID.

Comment: Не знаком с DLE, но я бы реализовал примерно так, добавил бы таблицу dontshowusernews(user_id, news_id) и при запросе списка статей отфильтровывал статьи конкретного пользователя которые присутствуют в этой таблице

Answer (score 0):

Дам общий алгоритм действий.

1. Спарсить ID юзера через переменную member_id
2. Проверить с базой (ну или как у вас там сделано). Если не показывать, то сделать обертку из php, куда поместить код с свойством display:none.
3. Один и тот же код, только выводить условием. Если разрешено, то выводишь код новости. Если запрещено, то тот же код, только со свойством display:none.